# IOS UITableViewCell strange behaviour of contentView

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints

I'm using **UITableViewCell** with dynamic height with worldwide techniques:

```
cell = _offCells[identifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    _offCells[identifier] = cell;
}

[cell setDataForSizeCalculation:data];


[cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];

CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
height += kPadding;
```

I have one Base **SSTableViewCell** class, which is extended if needed. I got two cells, subclasses of **SSTableViewCell**. Both have constraints *ContentView -> View -> otherElements.* Both cells are used in **estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath** method, of course, with needed height.

**The problem is:** in one case the cell is inited with height **282** (**needed height**), but in other case the cell is inited with default height **44** (**the standard height, not needed, needed is 106**).
I've checked the height in **awakeFromNib** method.

Checked on IOS 7,8.

### UPD

I've checked the storyboard file as XML, what i've found

**First case. Normal case**

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" hidesAccessoryWhenEditing="NO" indentationLevel="1" indentationWidth="0.0" reuseIdentifier="row.photo" rowHeight="282" id="Hfm-sq-86v" customClass="SSPhotoTableViewCell">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="1" width="320" height="282"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="Hfm-sq-86v" id="9TR-fJ-qX2">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="282"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
<userGuides>
<userLayoutGuide location="315" affinity="minX"/>
<userLayoutGuide location="10" affinity="minX"/>
</userGuides>
<subviews>
```

**Second case. Problem case**

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="none" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="user.row.photo" rowHeight="106" id="NRG-Xo-osO" customClass="SSUserPhotoTableViewCell">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="162" width="320" height="44"/>
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="NRG-Xo-osO" id="jxh-XR-Ksx">
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
<subviews>
```

### Question

1. <strike>Why this is happened?</strike>  (see **UPD**)
2. <strike>How to solve this problem?</strike> (see **UPD**)
3. Why in **Problem case** *tableViewCell* has wrong **frame**?
4. Why in **Problem case** *autoresizingMask* has additional properties (*flexibleMaxX, flexibleMaxY*)?
5. Why in **Problem case** *tableViewCellContentView* does not have property **frame**?

**Comment:** *Of course, after manual changes in storyboard xml, everything works well, without any NSLayoutConstraint warnings.*